# Dynamics AX 2009 - Promoting a New Field Security Key to Live

Tags: security, axapta, dynamics-ax-2009

We have an AX 2009 live environment running 4 companies.

As part of our development process we have been adding a number of new fields to forms, and applying security keys to these fields so that they can be restricted to certain groups and companies.

Our problem is that, by default, when we promote one of these new fields to the live environment, they are visible to everyone. We then apply security settings to ensure that only particular users in a particular company have access to see this new field.

Is there a way that we can set the default for a security key so that we reverse this process? i.e. can the new security key be defaulted as not visible/accessible to any user in any group until we have granted them access?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can change the default.

If you use security keys, you could XPO-import them to Live before doing the total release.

Then you could do the security setup before going live with the fields.

Comment: That is the current process. The more I investigate the issue, I think there may be a problem with the structure/design of security in our system. When a new security key is added it should really be as straight forward as setting no access at the top level (for example "AllUsers"), cascading that setting, then work on allowing access for specific groups.

Comment: This issue has turned out to be one of bad business process. Thanks for your help Jan.